# Timeline app that offer private embeddable timelines

Tags: web-apps, time-management

I am in search of a timeline app for use at my company.  It will be used to map release and deployment timelines for multiple product lines and so needs these features:

1. Offers private/protected timelines to be created
2. Private timelines are embeddable in other sites (like a Google Site, for example)
3. Allows for adding both single date events as well as time-spanning events
4. Offers layers or swim lanes for the different product lines
5. The ability to import a CSV file to populate (and manage) the timeline
6. Offers the ability to maintain a fixed scale, and side scroll to see timeline items off the screen.  Many timeline apps provide a slider with which you can adjust the scale, but I have not found one that offers scrolling instead.

Ideally, this app would be a part of the Google Apps marketplace so that it is more easily embeddable in google sites, but being in the Google Apps Marketplace is not a hard requirement.

Comment: I use [YouTrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) running on a local server. That s free, but you can pay for hosting.